# Doing assignment in Break condition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, breakpoints

While testing something, I had to replace string (many times!) while feeling lazy to stop debugger and write up my code. Instead I thought I can do this in Break condition to see if it works.

So the break condition looks like this:

`(someString = someString.Replace(".xx.", ".yy.")) != ""`

Which would evaluate to true every time.

But it doesn't do the assignment. Can someone explain why the condition is evaluated correctly, but assignment never happens?

Comment: Works fine for me. It does the assignment also

Comment: Your code works as expected. http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/yGy5JKyHYEGjIvBycdTBWQ

Comment: Yes, of course it works if written normally, but why not inside Break condition?

Comment: Not sure why people downvote without providing a reason?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel inside the break condition in debugger?

Comment: @Yahya Yes inside the break condition window. I tried with integer for simplicity.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel doesn't work for string strangely :S

Comment: Works with strings also. Just tried.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I was trying it in VS2013?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the Watch or Immediate windows instead. The purpose of the Break condition is to break when an expression is true, not to continuously change a real value.

It's quite a bizarre need IMHO.

Comment: Well, that's not really my question. I was doing it in Immediate Window and got bored :)